# PDF Implementation in dotnet Core - DinkTOPdf

Tags: .net-core, pdf-generation, dinktopdf

Implementation of dinktopdf nugget
Nugget link:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Haukcode.DinkToPdf/1.1.2?_src=template

Can anyone share the steps to implement for pdf file generation in .netCore?
How to generate template before sending a file as stream to genrate a pdf?

How to inject dependency in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for implementation:

- Use nugget from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Haukcode.DinkToPdf/1.1.2?_src=template
- generate template from html using handlebars(javascript library)

```cs
public class PdfExportTemplateBuilder : BaseTemplate
    {
public static string BuildTemplate(EmployeeDetails employessDetails, string id, string name)
        {
            var html = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(GetCurrentFolder(), @"EMPLOYEE\Template.Pdf.Employee.html")); //create the folder in current Assembly
            html = html.Replace(ID_PLACEHOLDER, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) ? "---" : id);
            html = html.Replace(NAME_PLACEHOLDER, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ? "---" : name);
            html = html.Replace(REPORT_DATE, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
            html = html.Replace(REPORT_YEAR, DateTime.UtcNow.Year.ToString());
            var template = Handlebars.Compile(html);
            return template(employessDetails);
        }
}

   public class BaseTemplate
    {

        protected const string ID_PLACEHOLDER= "{{ID}}";
        protected const string NAME_PLACEHOLDER= "{{NAME}}";
     }
```

- Pass the html template to convert to PDF

```cs
 public async Task<Stream> DownloadPdfAsync(User loggedInUser, string name)
        {
            
                    var html = PdfExportTemplateBuilder .BuildTemplate(employeeDetails,id,name);
                    var conversionOptions = new ConversionOptions
                    {
                        Margins = new MarginSettings(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    };

                    var pdfStream = new MemoryStream(_htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(html, conversionOptions));
                    pdfStream.Position = 0;

                    return pdfStream; //returns file as stream 
//Access as  return File(result, "application/pdf", "EmployeeDetails.pdf") from calling function.
                }
           
        }
```

- _htmlToPdfConverter Implementation

```cs
public class HtmlToPdfConverter : IHtmlToPdfConverter
    {
        private readonly IConverter _converter;

        private const string FontName = "Arimo, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
        private const string CenterFooterText = "Page [page] of [toPage]";
        private const string RightFooterTextFormat = "Report Date: {0}";
        private const int FontSize = 6;
        private const double Spacing = 7;

        public HtmlToPdfConverter(IConverter converter) => _converter = converter;

        public byte[] ConvertHtml(string html, ConversionOptions conversionOptions)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                GlobalSettings = {
                    ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                    Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                    Margins = conversionOptions.Margins,
                },
                Objects = {
                    new ObjectSettings() {
                        PagesCount = true,
                        HtmlContent = html,
                        WebSettings = { EnableIntelligentShrinking = false },
                        FooterSettings = {
                            FontSize = FontSize,
                            FontName = FontName,
                            Right = string.Format(RightFooterTextFormat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                            Center = CenterFooterText,
                            Spacing = Spacing
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            return _converter.Convert(doc);
        }
    }
```

- Inject dependency in Startup.cs (for .Net core)

```cs
            services.AddSingleton<IHtmlToPdfConverter, HtmlToPdfConverter>();
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new 
            SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
```